# How to install Fixblobs.py?

Tags: plone

How should I install [fixblobs.py](http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/01/05/fixing-poskeyerror-no-blob-file-content-in-plone/)? Is there anyone who made a product out of this to ease using this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Plone add-on

http://developer.plone.org/getstarted/

Make sure it uses Grok framework

http://developer.plone.org/components/grok.html

Drop the .py file anywhere in your addon.

Call the view via URL.

Though the code in the question is directed to developers who have experience doing this and it might be little risky to try to apply this code without actually undestanding what happens in those lines and how they might affect your site.

Comment: I can read and understand the code but I have no experience with Grok and I was wondering whether somebody already made a product out of this.